Finding a faint line in a very noisy image with variable background noise
I have a very noisy greyscale image where the noise level modulates along one axis. Within this image, there may be a very faint line of some unknown width. I want to be able to identify when this line is in the image. The application I have in mind requires this to be automated.
The following code can be used to generate two synthetic examples.
[Plot of back], an extreme example.

[Plot of back2], a less extreme example.

import numpy as np

def background(N, M, nl, nf, nT, r):
    a = nf*np.sin((2*np.pi/nT)*np.arange(N))
    a=a.reshape(-1,1)
    fuzz = nl + a*np.ones((N,M))
    fuzz+= r*a*np.random.normal(size=(N,M))

    return fuzz

def add_slider(B, s, v, w, a, r):
    N, M = B.shape
    amps = a+r*np.random.normal(size=M)

    x=np.arange(N)
    for i, y in enumerate(range(s, N, v)):
        if i >= M: break
        B[:,i]+=amps[i]*np.exp(-(x-y)**2/(2*w**2))

def subtracted(im):
    return im - im.mean(1).reshape(-1, 1)

B = background(1000, 300, 0, 5, 100, 1)
add_slider(B, 0, 2, 40, 1, 1)
back = subtracted(B)

# For a less extreme example:

B2 = gs.background(1000, 300, 0, 5, 100, 1)
gs.add_slider(B2, 0, 2, 40, 5, 1)
back2 = subtracted(B2)

I've tried a number of things, but none of them work very well when I change some of the parameters used to generate the image. For example, I've tried applying a Gaussian blur, which works sometimes, but getting the right width can be very finicky, and it struggles when the line is more vertical. I've also tried a rotating mask like in this post, but it seems to get thwarted by the modulating noise level. I've also done a little experimenting with radon transforms, but I can't find anything consistent there either. Most standard edge detection methods like Canny don't seem to work, because they tend to rely on local gradients, which get totally ruined by noise.
I've done some limited searching for papers on this topic, but I haven't found anything that suits this problem well. If possible, I want to find a solution that doesn't rely on knowing much about the line, like its thickness.

can you share a true non-synthetic example as well? what physical process generates, or is imaged in, these pictures?

Is this FFT image of something? If does, I want to say that the denoising should be performed before your FFT. If not, maybe you can remove line using canny algorithm to detect line edge and you can get the vector of line. and using inner product with vertical line to determine whether the apt angle threshold to remove your noise

Does the "white line" you seek always start in top-left (or at least a known) corner? Does it always extend fully to the right (or at least a known) side?

@NoYeah The data is FFT related, but likely not in the way you're thinking. The image would come from a series of FFTs taken off an instrument, so you should think of the vertical access as the frequency domain and the horizontal axis as some parameter I'm sweeping; I'm essentially looking for a peak that moves. The noise comes from actual physical sources that I don't have much control over.

@MarkSetchell I can make some limited assumptions about the line. It doesn't necessarily start in the very top left, but it will start somewhere at the top and move southeast. In principle, it should extend across the image, but whether it leaves the image at the right or the bottom is unknown.

@ChristophRackwitz The actual data data would be a series of FFTs pulled off an instrument. You can think of the vertical axis as the frequency domain and the horizontal axis as some parameter I'm sweeping. For the example images I've provided, I already do a mean background subtraction on the horizontal axis. I'm essentially looking for a peak that moves. Unfortunately, I can't really provide a non-synthetic example, particularly one with the feature in it, because the point of this is to figure out where the feature might be.

“I can't really provide a non-synthetic example, particularly one with the feature in it, because the point of this is to figure out where the feature might be.“ If you want to automate this process, you need real data to develop and test the program. Synthetic data usually does not match the noise and other characteristics of real data. I’m confident that if I write code to detect the line in these images, it will not work in your real data. So as long as your question is vague, all we can do is give vague suggestions.

One vague suggestion: if you want to detect lines, don’t use an edge detector. Edge =/= line. There are many line detectors in the literature (also called ridge detector). They often involve 2nd order derivatives. Look for example for “Frangi vesselness”.

still too vague for me to give good advice. I also don't buy the "can't give real data" justifications because that's "I don't want to give real data". some flawed reasoning too (you assume the feature is there, so don't say it isn't just because you don't know where). the usual filtering and thresholding may serve you well enough, but you'll have to do that on real data before you can say if it works. we don't even know what you want to do with the information, like in what format you need this information, what depends on this extracted information, ... I'm giving up at this point.

Here is another approach in Imagemagick 7 basically doing an -auto-threshold otsu followed by a median filter.
Note that I cropped your image to remove the added borders.
Input 1:

magick test.png -auto-threshold otsu -statistic median 21x21 test1_thresh_median.png


Input 2:

magick test2.png -auto-threshold otsu -statistic median 51x51 test2_thresh_median.png



I don't have OpenCV to hand, but can obtain pretty reasonable results with ImageMagick which can be readily ported to OpenCV if the technique looks useable for your needs.
Basically I am calculating the mean of a 3px wide by 30px tall box at each pixel location and contrast stretching the result. This is your fainter image:
magick input.png -statistic mean 3x30 -auto-level result.png


